# R + Studio errors on Windows vs MacOS

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

I have some basic R code demo in RStudio (1.4.1103) that executes
without error on my MacOS (11.6) MacBook.
Same code throws errors when run on students' Windows 10 laptops (same R and Studio as on MacBook)

Errors like...

> plot(stdata$region)
> **Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values**

> plot(stdata$region, stdata$teacherpay,

- ```
   main="Example Plot", xlab="Region", ylab="Teacher Pay", col="red")
  ```

**Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values**

...and oddly,

> plot(stdata$satmath, stdata$satverbal, col=stdata$region)
> **Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid color name 'ESC'**

which colors perfectly fine on my MacBook but doesn't transform
the color() value on the Windows installs.

What's going on with Windows+R+RStudio?!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: basic R source code added